# Why toBinaryString is not an instance method in Integer class?

Tags: java, design-patterns

A simple design question.

Sample code:

```
    Integer int1 = new Integer(20);     
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(int1));
```

Why JDK design is not something like the following? so, toBinaryString function *returns* the the desired result?

```
    System.out.println(int1.toBinaryString());
```

Aside for wide usability of a static function, what are the *other reasons* for this design approach? Are they using any particular design pattern? If it is then, which pattern?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your sample code creates an instance of `Integer` and then unboxes it. There's no need for that:

```
int int1 = 20;
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(int1);
```

If it were an instance method, you'd be *forced* to create an instance of `Integer` solely to convert an `int` to its binary representation, which would be annoying.

In other words: to avoid creating objects unnecessarily.

Comment: To avoid *explicitly* creating objects unnecessarily, no?  Autoboxing will end up creating essentially identical bytecode in either case.  (Now, Hotspot might elide the object creation altogether, but again that would apply to both cases equally). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jon-skeet lets just say `int` type does't exists. Then what would be the reason behind this design pattern?

Comment: Andrzej: No, there won't be any autoboxing, because the parameter type it `int`, not `Integer`.

Comment: @iamcreasy: But `int` *does* exist in the world where this was designed. If it *didn't* exist, I suspect the method wouldn't be designed in the same way.

Comment: @jon-skeet then what design would be preferred? `int1.toBinaryString()` is this one?

Comment: @iamcreasy: Yes, if `int` didn't exist, I think that would be more appropriate.

Comment: @jon-skeet Thanks. That's what I was asking. :)

Answer (score 15):

This is because you can't have two methods with the same name, one static and one instance. Having two different method names for the same functionality again would have been confusing.

Putting in a static method seemed more logical since in that case you wouldn't have to "wrap" an int into an Integer before getting its binary representation and it serves both the purposes (binary string for `int` and for `Integer`).

Comment: I know it. My question is why jdk is designed in this way.

Comment: I already answered that; it is so because you don't have to wrap an `int` to an `Integer` and also to prevent having two methods in the class (one static and one not) doing the same thing.

Comment: +1 I suspect this is the answer - because `int` isn't an object, but autoboxing lets you pretend it is one when *passed* to a method (but not when invoking a method on it).  `Integer.toBinaryString(42)` compiles, but `42.toBinaryString()` doesn't.

Comment: @sanjay-t-sharma So does this designs approach has any name?

Comment: @Jon-Skeet: Of course; my mistake.  In retrospect there's absolutely no reason why it *would* take an `Integer` rather than an `int` since the logic would just unwrap the primitive value anyway.  D'oh.

Comment: @Sanjay T. Sharma nice answer +1

Answer (score 6):

Back when this method was added, in JDK1.0.2, there was no autoboxing, and JVMs were much slower than now. I imagine that having this static method allowed converting both an int and an Integer to a binary string easily, and without having to create a new Integer instance just for the conversion of an int to binary.

Answer (score 0):

int, char, double ... these are default datatype, these are not the object. Method should be part of an Object not datatype.

Such static method more efficient than instance method.